# Select only the most recent value for each identifier in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this:

```
identifier | value | tstamp
-----------+-------+---------------------
abc        | 21    | 2014-01-05 05:24:31
xyz        | 16    | 2014-01-11 03:32:04
sdf        | 11    | 2014-02-06 07:04:24
qwe        | 24    | 2014-02-14 02:12:07
abc        | 23    | 2014-02-17 08:45:24
sdf        | 15    | 2014-03-21 11:23:17
xyz        | 19    | 2014-03-27 09:52:37
```

I know how to get the most recent value for a single identifier:

```
select * from table where identifier = 'abc' order by tstamp desc limit 1;
```

But I want to get the most recent value for all identifiers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest (and often fastest) way is `DISTINCT ON` in Postgres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (identifier) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY identifier, tstamp DESC;
```

This also returns an ordered list.
[SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ecc8f/1)
Details:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen your answer. It works, and is the fastest according to `explain analyze`.

Comment: +1, I had no idea about `DISTINCT ON ()` in postgres

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY identifier 
                                  ORDER BY tstamp DESC)  AS RN
        FROM YourTable) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ebe57/2) an sqlfiddle with a demo of this.

The results are:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════════════╦════╗
║ IDENTIFIER ║ VALUE ║             TSTAMP              ║ RN ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════╣
║ abc        ║    23 ║ February, 17 2014 08:45:24+0000 ║  1 ║
║ qwe        ║    24 ║ February, 14 2014 02:12:07+0000 ║  1 ║
║ sdf        ║    15 ║ March, 21 2014 11:23:17+0000    ║  1 ║
║ xyz        ║    19 ║ March, 27 2014 09:52:37+0000    ║  1 ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════════════╩════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any benefits to this approach compared to the `DISTINCT ON` answer?

Comment: @BLuFeNiX I actually didn't know about `DISTINCT ON` in postgres, so I can't really compare both methods.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX: One benefit would be that window functions work in all modern RDBMS (except MySQL), while `DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres specific extension of the standard SQL `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: You can also resolve ties easily and in different ways - using other ranking functions like `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` - which you can't do with `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: this needs a desc index,i dont want to maintain 2 indexes as that slows performance, anything that can be done about it

Answer (score 2):

Filter out everything but the newest identifier like this:

```
select * from table t
where not exists 
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM table x
      WHERE x.identifier = t.identifier
        AND x.tstamp > t.tstamp
     ) ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do; I think you may have misinterpreted my question. Thanks, though!

Comment: @BLuFeNiX The query is fine (now, after the edit.) It's a valid way to solve the problem.

Comment: When I originally posted, I forgot to include x.identifier = t.identifier. Thank you for fixing @ypercube

Answer (score 1):

Simply join the table with itself, Add "<" as a join condition, and use the result where the *right* timestamp is null - then there is NO larger item for the defined identifier)

```
 SELECT t1.* FROM tbl t1
   LEFT JOIN tbl t2
   ON t1.identifier = t2.identifier AND
    t1.tstamp < t2.tstamp
   WHERE t2.tstamp is null
```

Stolen fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/39e7a/4

Comment: Thanks! Are there any benefits to this approach compared to the `DISTINCT ON` answer?